# Invert PNG graphics file with a non-interactive command

Tags: drupal, shell, image-processing, png

I'm using [DruTex](http://drupal.org/project/drutex), which is a Drupal module to embed Latex equations. The context of the equation is marked, and a Latex interpreter will generate a PNG file:

```
dvipng -o [IMG_FILE] -D [DPI] -T tight [TMP_DIR]/[HASH].dvi
```

The dvipng utility is used to generate a PNG from Latex's DVI file. That's good so far, but I could need black background and white foreground for these equations, since otherwise they are hard to read, because they appear in a dark-themed way.

`convert` (from Imagemagick) doesn't have an `-invert` flag. Neither does `dvipng`. So is there a way to invert a png file? I can add something to that routine like:

```
batch_invert -input [IMG_FILE] -out [IMG_FILE]
```

However I do not know how I can implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convert` has a `-negate` option that works.

Example:

`convert -negate input.png output.png`